# iOS customise user interface

Tags: ios, swift

Hi all I would like to make a horizontal scroll bar like below in iOS APP.

[image]

I read through lots of iOS programming book, none of them teaches me how to do custom UI. Can someone tell me, what knowledge I should learn in order to make this?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `UICollectionView` to make your life easier. There are many [tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started) on that in which you probably just want to lay out your cells in one row and many columns to achieve the horizontal scrolling effect. Otherwise you may want to employ external libraries like [this](https://github.com/terenceLuffy/AppStoreStyleHorizontalScrollView) if you prefer a plug and play solution.

Comment: Thanks so much, how about the red colour bar in the horizontal scroll bar? Can advise how can I make it?

Comment: I would add a red-filled rectangles to the appropriate UIView cell (it should be a lower z-index than the text). If the red bar extends over a longer timespan, I would draw contiguous rectangles over the corresponding cells.